# WPF Prism - load view dynamically in pop up window

Tags: wpf, view, popup, prism

We have multiple project solution based on MS Prism in WPF. For ease of understanding lets take we have project shell, and project usercontrol. The usercontrol project has numerous views for various functions. We have a pop up window in shell project which is called from main shell window, what i want is to load different view into pop up window region manager based on requirement. Any help/suggestion through flow explanation or some code samples will be highly appreciable.

Regards

Comment: Can you elaborate on "based on requirement".  Showing a registered view in another view is simple using regions, however I feel like the "based on requirement" comment might complicate things a little.

Comment: "based on requirement" -> we have one main shell window and another window which we intend to use as a pop up (e.g. to filter a grid, or to pick/insert data from an option in a grid). this pop up window has a region defined in it, we want to show/load different views in the region "based on requirement :)" i.e. as per the required option

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PopupRegionBehavior` that comes with the Prism-v2 [RI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458919.aspx) to achieve what you are trying to do in a decoupled way. You can read more about it [here](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=65394).

Please let me know if this helps.

Thanks,
Damian

Answer (score 1):

Using a Dependency Injection Container (such as [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity/) which can also be obtained from the CompositeWPF [Microsoft page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=387C7A59-B217-4318-AD1B-CBC2EA453F40&displaylang=en)), you'll be able to pass around an instance of `IRegionManager` to your various modules/pop-up windows...

For example, in the view you wish to inject another view into, you could have a named ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="Modules" />
```

To fill it with your custom view, all you'd have to do from code is:

```
_regionManager.Regions["Modules"].Add(view);
```

(Where `_regionManager` could be an instance variable populated via Dependency Injection to the constructor of the class it's in).  Don't worry about registering the `IRegionManager` interface with the container, that's done by the UnityBootstrapper during configuration.